# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator

Tags: java, sql, code-generation, jooq

I'm encountering the following exception after upgrading from jOOQ 3.10 to 3.11:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass (GenerationTool.java:819)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:329)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:220)
    at org.jooq.codegen.maven.Plugin.execute (Plugin.java:195)
```

What's the reason for this? Has this class been deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Reusing `org.jooq.util` package names in older Java versions

Older jOOQ versions had a package name conflict between the `jooq` and `jooq-meta` / `jooq-codegen` artefacts, which all reused the `org.jooq.util` package. This was OK in older versions of Java, up to Java 8.

#### Forward compatibility for Java 9 / JPMS

Under the JPMS, starting with Java 9, this is no longer allowed when running code on the module path (as opposed to the legacy classpath). For forwards compatibility, [when jOOQ will be modularised](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6612), the offending packages in `jooq-meta` and `jooq-codegen` have been renamed:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7419

Packages in the following code generation modules now have these prefixes:

- `jooq-meta`: `org.jooq.meta`
- `jooq-meta-extensions`: `org.jooq.meta.extensions`
- `jooq-codegen`: `org.jooq.codegen`
- `jooq-codegen-maven`: `org.jooq.codegen.maven`

The `jooq` module (the runtime) did not change its package names.

#### See also

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7419
- https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/71
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/-ILukM1EvlM
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/CRFH6qhh8Rk

Answer (score 0):

Replace all

```
org.jooq.util.
```

with

```
org.jooq.meta.
```

All done.