# Spring Boot JOOQ Integration - compilation issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I already went through link: [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793357/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-jooq-util-javagenerator) and following https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/03/springboot-working-jooq.html. I am using **Java8** and **Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE**.

I build the project using `>mvn clean install -P mysql`, but its giving me below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass0 (GenerationTool.java:925)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.loadClass (GenerationTool.java:869)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0 (GenerationTool.java:357)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:221)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:216)
    at org.jooq.codegen.maven.Plugin.execute (Plugin.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.jasper</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-jooq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-jooq</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>h2</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                                <version>${h2.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:h2:~/springbootjooq</url>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes />
                                    <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>com.example.jooq.model</packageName>
                                    <directory>gensrc/main/java</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mysql</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                                <version>${mysql.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
                                <user>root</user>
                                <password>root</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes />
                                    <inputSchema>test</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>com.example.jooq.model</packageName>
                                    <directory>gensrc/main/java</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the jooq version in mvn dependency:tree

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha - Its `<jooq.version>3.12.3</jooq.version>`, could you please guide me here for new issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444988/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-jooq-util-jaxb-tools-xmlappenda

Comment: I have answered there, the key point in all this is, you need to really understand what are the certain library you are using in your code, accordingly you have to add the dependencies. If you are following any article, read in totality. also refer the main document for that library.  You should look at the dependency tree and see if anything missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpringBoot 2.2.2 JOOQ starter add jooq 3.12.3 and JOOQ code generation moved to separate library. Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, **org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator** is deprecated and you can use **org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator**.

Comment: @Siva - Its giving me `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jooq.util.jaxb.tools.XMLAppendable`. I've posted new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444988/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-jooq-util-jaxb-tools-xmlappenda